# shell file not found by jenkins pipe

Tags: shell, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkins pipeline for my react project. After build, I want to deploy in my nginx server. I use the stage :

```
  stage('Deploy') { 
        steps {
            sh 'chmod +x /var/jenkins_home/workspace/gara-developer-console/scripts/deploy-int.sh'
            sh '.$(pwd)/scripts/deploy-int.sh'
        }
    }
```

My script is inside my project under the forlder scripts/deploy-int.sh

The content is very simple :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Starting deployment in the nginx server"
set -x
cp -R ../dist/* /home/nginx/console/

echo "Done. You can check your server"
```

During the steps (Deploy) I got the error :

```
+ chmod +x /var/jenkins_home/workspace/gara-developer-console/scripts/deploy-int.sh
[Pipeline] sh
+ pwd
+ ./var/jenkins_home/workspace/gara-developer-console/scripts/deploy-int.sh
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/gara-developer-console@tmp/durable-a9d5fdce/script.sh: line 1: ./var/jenkins_home/workspace/gara-developer-console/scripts/deploy-int.sh: not found
[Pipeline] }
```

Please, do you know how to find a solution ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why you add . before pwd?

Comment: @Lamanus to have dynamically the path, but even if I remove, I have the same error

Comment: Please could you help me ?